# How to filter the DataGridView using ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, filter, combobox

I need help on filtering my `DataGridView` using `ComboBox`

Here's my display code

```
cm = new SqlCommand();
cn = new SqlConnection(lgn.connections);
cn.Open();
cm.Connection = cn;
query = "Select * from Trails";
cm.CommandText = query;
SqlDataAdapter dar = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dar.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 0;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 130;
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 100;
dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 360;
dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 130;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

RAW DATA:

```
ID  | TRANSACTYPE | DESCRIPTION | AUTHORIZED BY
-----------------------------------------------
1   | LOGIN       | blah blah   | BOB
2   | LOGOUT      | blah blah   | BOB
3   | LOGIN       | blah blah   | TIM
4   | LOGOUT      | blah blah   | KURT
```

I have `ComboBox` named `cboFilter` and if I changed the index to `LOGIN` the data that will show on the `dataGridView1` is only LOGINs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

private void cboFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("TRANSACTYPE  LIKE '%{0}%'", cboFilter.SelectedItem.ToString());
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `DataGridView` data source always to be a `DataTable` as in my case.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
dgv.DataSource = dt.Select("IsActive = 1").CopyToDataTable();
```