# How to filter datagridview based on combobox selection

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, filter, combobox

I have a `DatagridView` contains students information, including class, age, etc. now I want to create a ComboBox that have function to filter which class (for example if I select class IIA on combobox, the `datagridview` only show students from class IIA).

Here is my code in the form to load the data from `objectbindingsource`:

```
private void frmdbSiswa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db = new SiswaSMSEntities();
    tabelSiswaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.ToList();
    agamaSiswaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Agama_Siswa.ToList();
    kelasBindingSource.DataSource = db.Kelas.ToList();
    jenisKelaminBindingSource.DataSource = db.Jenis_Kelamin.ToList();

    dataGridViewSiswa.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.ToList();//to show the datagridview
    cboKelas.DataSource = db.Kelas.ToList();//combobox
}
```

and here is the code for combobox:

```
private void cboKelas_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridViewSiswa.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.Where(x => x.IdKelas == cboKelas.SelectedIndex).ToList();
}
```

I also bind the combobox to the datasource.
I am so confuse for hours working on this. I am new to programming, so please forgive me if I am asking a very basic question.

The problem is, when I run the code, it does filter the data, but when I select the class IA, datagridview shows nothing, and when I select class IB, the datagridview shows students from class IA and so on. and also when I select the datagridview, combobox on show `system.Data.Entity.Error`.

Comment: not sure what you meant by _now I want to create a ComboBox that have function to filter which data shown on the DatagridView_

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I have edit the question

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: Thank you for your respond @ChetanRanpariya I have edit the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter the DataGridView using ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422267/how-to-filter-the-datagridview-using-combobox)

Answer (score 0):

Upon combo box selection changed event, set data grid view RowFilter property to selected value :

```
dv.RowFilter = "YourColumnName = ComboBoxSelectedValue";
```

Updating this with similar problem/solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422267/how-to-filter-the-datagridview-using-combobox)

Comment: I have add the code, but it doesn't work @RahulAgarwal

Comment: @OktavianusMisro to make sure i undertood your ask correctly, tell me one thing - what you looking for is different from ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422267/how-to-filter-the-datagridview-using-combobox) ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer hehe, I am going to try this

Answer (score 0):

Repalce this Add !IsPostBack in Page Load

```
private void frmdbSiswa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
 {
    db = new SiswaSMSEntities();
    tabelSiswaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.ToList();
    agamaSiswaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Agama_Siswa.ToList();
    kelasBindingSource.DataSource = db.Kelas.ToList();
    jenisKelaminBindingSource.DataSource = db.Jenis_Kelamin.ToList();

    dataGridViewSiswa.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.ToList();//to show the datagridview
    dataGridViewSiswa.DataBind();
    cboKelas.DataSource = db.Kelas.ToList();//combobox
    cboKelas.DataBind();
   }
}

private void cboKelas_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridViewSiswa.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.Where(x => x.IdKelas == cboKelas.SelectedIndex).ToList();
 dataGridViewSiswa.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast respond, @NegiRox but, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
            cmb.Name = "cmb";
            cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
            cmb.Items.Add("True");
            cmb.Items.Add("False");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);

        }
    }
}
```

Post back if you have additional questions.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-combobox.htm

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely have to have a `List<T>` as a `DataSource` to the grid, I suggest you use a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid. It may make things easier and it appears you may already have the `DataTable` from `db.Tabel_Siswa.ToList()` which appears to be making a list FROM a table.

With that said, below is an example of using a combo box to filter the data in a grid using a `DataTable` and a `DataView`. It is a simple form with an empty `DataGridView` and an empty `ComboBox`. A global `DataTable` variable `gridTable` is used as a `DataSource` to the grid. A global `DataView` variable `dv` is used to “filter/unFilter” the `gridTable`.

Upon form load, columns and some test data is added to the `gridTable`. Then the `gridTable` is set as a `DataSource` to the grid. Lastly the `ComboBox` is filled with items “Class A, Class B” etc… A “No Filter” selection is added to the combo box to allow the user to remove an applied filter.

When the user changes the combo box selection, a new `DataView` is created and it’s `RowFilter` is set to the selected value in the combo box. Finally, the `DataView` `dv` is set as a `DataSource` to the grid to display the filtered results

```
DataTable gridTable;
DataView dv;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  gridTable = GetTable();
  FillTable(gridTable);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = gridTable;
  SetComboBox();
}

private void SetComboBox() {
  comboBox1.Items.Add("No Filter");
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Class A");
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Class B");
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Class C");
  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("FName", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("LName", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Class", typeof(string));
  return dt;
}

private void FillTable(DataTable dt) {
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add("FName" + i, "LName" + i, "Class A");
    dt.Rows.Add("FName" + i, "LName" + i, "Class B");
    dt.Rows.Add("Class" + i, "Class" + i, "Class C");
  }
}
```

The `RowFilter` string… `dv.RowFilter = "Class = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'"` says to filter such that the cells in the column named “Class” equals the text in the combo box. Example: “Class = Class B”. This implies that the `DataSource` has a column name that “matches” what’s in the filter string.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dv = new DataView(gridTable);
  if (comboBox1.Text == "No Filter")
    dv.RowFilter = "";
  else
    dv.RowFilter = "Class = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank youuuuuu, I'm going to try this @JohnG. It seems that this lead me to the right direction.

Comment: Do I need to delete this tabelSiswaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Tabel_Siswa.ToList();
agamaSiswaBindingSource.DataSource = db.Agama_Siswa.ToList();
kelasBindingSource.DataSource = db.Kelas.ToList();
jenisKelaminBindingSource.DataSource = db.Jenis_Kelamin.ToList(); @JohnG

Comment: I am guessing deleting may not be the best idea. Without knowing what a `SiswaSMSEntities();` returns, removing the `.ToList()` may work. I am guessing from the name `db.Tabel_Siswa`… that this is a `DataTable`. In addition, my code is using a `DataTable` and it appears you may be using a `BindingSource`. This data table may still work for the `BindingSource`, however you will most likely have to use the `BindingSource`s “filter” properties. Lastly, for the combo box you should use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead of the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your kindness,  I am working on this. I'll vote your answer if its work. Thank you @JohnG